# Changing <title> with Lift

Tags: scala, dynamic, title, lift

Is it possible to dynamically switch the title of a page that is served by Lift without having to write an extra snippet for that particular case?

One option is of course `<lift:mySnippet><title>Default Title</title></lift:mySnippet>` but I thought there might be an option along the lines of `<head_merge><title>New Title</title></head_merge>` (which inserts a second title node).

I do not like the first approach since I do not want to stick all the title generation logic into a single snippet and ask what kind of page I am on etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried to use templates?

You can define template in `templates-hidden/default.html` like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:lift="http://liftweb.net/">

    <head>
        <title>
            <lift:bind name="title" />
        </title>

        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        <lift:bind name="content" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And use it in `index.html` for example:

```
<lift:surround with="default">
    <lift:bind-at name="title">Home</lift:bind-at>
    <lift:bind-at name="content">
        my content
    </lift:bind-at>
</lift:surround>
```

You can find more information about templates here:

http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki?id=liftweb&wiki_id=Templates_and_Binding

Comment: If you are using the HTML5 support in Lift, you'll need to change your default.html to use <title class="lift:Menu.title">%*%</title> as HTML5 doesn't support tags inside of the title element.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the `Menu.title` snippet.

In `bootstrap/liftweb/Boot.scala` you define the sitemap with page names:

```
class Boot {
  def boot {
    // ...
    def sitemap = SiteMap(
      Menu.i("Home") / "index",
      Menu.i("About") / "about")
    // ...
  }
}
```

In `templates-hidden/default.html` you use the snippet:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:lift="http://liftweb.net/">
<head>
  ...
  <title class="lift:Menu.title">AppName:</title>
  ...
```

Then page titles will be: "AppName: Home" and "AppName: About". This is nice if you use

```
<span class="lift:Menu.builder"></span>
```

to build the menu, because page titles will be the same used in the menu.

Another approach is to use [head merge](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki?id=liftweb&wiki_id=Templates_and_Binding#head_merge) and define the title in the page's html. For this to work, you have to remove the `<title>` tag from `templates-hidden/default.html` and put an `<head>` or `<head_merge>` tag in your content block:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body class="lift:content_id=main">
    <div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">
    <head_merge>
      <title>TITLE OF THIS PAGE HERE</title>
    </head_merge>
    ...
```